# unable to take user input in perl

Tags: perl, ssh, mod-perl

I am having a strange issue. I have written a script which is basically running a perl script in remote server using ssh.

This script is working fine but after completion of the above operation it will ask user to choose the next operation.

it is showing the options in the command prompt but while I am giving any input it is not showing in the screen even after hitting enter also it remain same.

I am not getting what is the exact issue, but it seems there is some issue with the ssh command because if I am commenting out the ssh command it is working fine.

```
OPERATION:
print "1: run the script in remote server \n2: Exit\n\nEnter your choice:";
my $input=<STDIN>;
chomp($input);
..........
sub run_script()
{
  my $com="sshg3.exe server -q --user=user --password=pass -exec script >/dev/null";
system("$com");

goto OPERATION;
}
```

after completing this ssh script it is showing in screen:

1: run remote script 
2: exit

Enter your choice:

but while I am giving any input it is not displaying in the screen until and unless I am exiting it using crtl C.

Please can anyone help what might be the issue here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the output in command prompt if -n option is not available for you.

try this one it might work for you.

```
system("$com />null");
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the classic gotchas with `ssh` is this - that it *normally* runs interactively, and as such will attach `STDIN` by default.

This can result in `STDIN` being consumed by `ssh` rather than your script.

Try it with `ssh -n` instead.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
but the problem is, as I am using third party SSH module to accomplish this, so there is no -n option for me. is there any other way to stop this ?

Answer (score 1):

As per https://support.ssh.com/manuals/client-user/62/sshg3.html there is an  option for redirecting input use `--dev-null (*nix) or --null (Windows)`.

```
-n, --dev-null (Unix), -n, --null (Windows)
Redirects input from /dev/null (Unix) and from NUL (Windows).
```